# Write premake4.lua file that builds and links to static libraries using premake

Tags: lua

I am trying to write a premake4.lua file that builds and links to static libraries using `premake`.

- library `mbm` was originally designed to be built using `cmake`. So to go around this issue I call `./configure` then I build it using `premake4 gmake`.
- library jansson was originally designed to be built using `cmake`. But calling `./configure` was not enough to build it, since `cmake` was also generating `jansson_config.h` that is needed for the build. So I ended up calling `premake` with `prebuildcommands` to build `jansson` using `cmake` first.

I don't think the way I built `jansson` is nice at all. Any idea how I can make this better?

premake.lua:

```
local homepath = os.getenv("HOME")

newoption {
   trigger     = "create-static-libs",
   description = "Creates all the necessary dependencies to build the ProjectA"
}

solution "ProjectA"
  configurations { "Debug", "Release"}

  configuration { "Debug" }
    objdir "../build/debug"
    targetdir "../install/bin/debug"

  configuration { "Release" }
    objdir "../build/release"
    targetdir "../install/bin/release"


  if _ACTION == "clean" then
    os.rmdir("../install")
    os.rmdir("../build")
  end

  project "mbm"
    kind "StaticLib"
    language "C"
    includedirs { "mbm/" }
    files{ "mbm/src/**.h","mbm/src/**.c"}

    configuration { "create-static-libs" }
      prebuildcommands { "cd mbm; ./configure; cd -; rm -rf config.log" }


  project "ProjectA"
    kind "ConsoleApp"
    language "C++"
    links {"mbm", "jansson"}
    includedirs { "include/**", "mbm/**", "jansson-2.7/**" }
    files { "bin/**.h", "bin/**.cpp" }

    configuration { "Debug*" }
      libdirs { "../install/bin/debug/" }
      defines { "_DEBUG", "DEBUG" }
      flags   { "Symbols" }

      if _OPTIONS[ "create-static-libs" ] then
        prebuildcommands { "cd jansson-2.7;./configure --prefix=".. homepath .."/eclipse_workspace/ProjectA/build/jansson --disable-shared;make config=debug;make install;cd -" }
        prebuildcommands { "mkdir -p ../install/bin/debug; mv ../build/jansson/lib/libjansson.a ../install/bin/debug/" }
      end

    configuration { "Release*" }
      libdirs { "../install/bin/release/" }
      defines { "NDEBUG" }
      flags   { "Optimize" }

      if _OPTIONS[ "create-static-libs" ] then
        prebuildcommands { "cd jansson-2.7;./configure --prefix=".. homepath .."/eclipse_workspace/ProjectA/build/jansson --disable-shared;make config=release;make install;cd -" }
        prebuildcommands { "mkdir -p ../install/bin/release; mv ../build/jansson/lib/libjansson.a ../install/bin/release/" }
      end
```

Comment: Which tag(s) do you need?